# How to stop air leaking out rims without sealant

Tags: tire, tubeless

How to stop air leaking  out rims without  sealant

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! You might want to add some details to your question, e.g. what general problem you are trying to solve, and which specific actions you've tried so far. This way it will attract more specific answers. As it is written now, it is too generic to usefully answer, I am afraid.

Comment: Install tubes..

Answer (score 9):

Two common alternatives exist to stop the air leaking from the wheel.

1. Use sealant.
2. Use inner tube.

Comment: Agreed - it has been discovered that using an air retention system greatly increases one’s chances of holding air in the tire.

Comment: Such a combination is rare to find these days, but you could add using a UST rim/tyre combo.  They were designed to be used without sealant, but people used sealant anyway for punctures, hence why it is largely abandoned in favour of lighter 'tubeless ready' tyres.